# Docker CrossCompile Debian build-essential:armhf unmet dependencies

Tags: debian, docker, cross-compilation

I try to move a VirtualBox VM to a docker image. We use the VirtualBox to crosscompile source code for a armhf device (something based on a BeagleBone)

I got problems at `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential:armhf`
The complete Docker code looks like this:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential module-assistant curl git cmake
RUN curl http://emdebian.org/tools/debian/emdebian-toolchain-archive.key | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://emdebian.org/tools/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/crosstools.list
RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y crossbuild-essential-armhf
RUN apt-get install -y curl:armhf
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev:armhf openssl:armhf 
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential:armhf
RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev:armhf
```

I get the following error when running docker build:

```
Step 12/13 : RUN apt-get install -y build-essential:armhf
 ---> Running in ca5a82d30cc7
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential:armhf : Depends: gcc:armhf (>= 4:4.9.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: g++:armhf (>= 4:4.9.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: make:armhf
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y build-essential:armhf' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

If i do look at the bash history on the VM  it looks the same. What is the problem with my Docker code?

EDIT: Output with -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes:

```
  Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) dpkg-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.17.27 > ( utils )
Broken dpkg-dev:amd64 Depends on make [ amd64 ] < 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:amd64 1 as a solution to dpkg-dev:amd64 2
  Added make:amd64 to the remove list
Broken dpkg-dev:amd64 Depends on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to dpkg-dev:amd64 2
  Added binutils:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing dpkg-dev:amd64 via keep of make:amd64
  Fixing dpkg-dev:amd64 via keep of binutils:amd64
Investigating (0) binutils [ armhf ] < none -> 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
Broken binutils:armhf Conflicts on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to binutils:armhf 2
  Added binutils:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing binutils:armhf via remove of binutils:amd64
Investigating (0) make [ amd64 ] < 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
Broken make:amd64 Conflicts on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to make:amd64 1
  Added make:armhf to the remove list
  Fixing make:amd64 via keep of make:armhf
Investigating (0) binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5 > ( devel )
Broken binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 Depends on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 1
  Removing binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 rather than change binutils:amd64
Investigating (1) build-essential [ armhf ] < none -> 11.7 > ( devel )
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Re-Instated make:armhf
Investigating (1) dpkg-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.17.27 > ( utils )
Broken dpkg-dev:amd64 Depends on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to dpkg-dev:amd64 2
  Added binutils:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing dpkg-dev:amd64 via keep of binutils:amd64
Investigating (1) gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf [ amd64 ] < 4.9.2-10 > ( devel )
Broken gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 Depends on binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5 > ( devel ) (>= 2.25)
  Considering binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 1 as a solution to gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 2
  Added binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 via keep of binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64
Investigating (1) binutils [ armhf ] < none -> 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
Broken binutils:armhf Conflicts on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to binutils:armhf 2
  Added binutils:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing binutils:armhf via remove of binutils:amd64
Investigating (1) make [ amd64 ] < 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
Broken make:amd64 Conflicts on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to make:amd64 1
  Added make:armhf to the remove list
  Fixing make:amd64 via keep of make:armhf
Investigating (1) binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5 > ( devel )
Broken binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 Depends on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 1
  Removing binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 rather than change binutils:amd64
Investigating (2) build-essential [ armhf ] < none -> 11.7 > ( devel )
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Considering make-guile:armhf -1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Re-Instated libgc1c2:armhf
  Re-Instated libltdl7:armhf
  Re-Instated libtinfo5:armhf
  Re-Instated libncurses5:armhf
  Re-Instated libreadline6:armhf
  Re-Instated libunistring0:armhf
  Re-Instated guile-2.0-libs:armhf
  Re-Instated make-guile:armhf
Investigating (2) dpkg-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.17.27 > ( utils )
Broken dpkg-dev:amd64 Depends on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 1 as a solution to dpkg-dev:amd64 2
  Added binutils:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing dpkg-dev:amd64 via keep of binutils:amd64
Investigating (2) gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf [ amd64 ] < 4.9.2-10 > ( devel )
Broken gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 Depends on binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5 > ( devel ) (>= 2.25)
  Considering binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 1 as a solution to gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 2
  Added binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64 via keep of binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64
Investigating (2) binutils [ armhf ] < none -> 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
Broken binutils:armhf Conflicts on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 2 as a solution to binutils:armhf 2
  Holding Back binutils:armhf rather than change binutils:amd64
Investigating (2) make [ amd64 ] < 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
Broken make:amd64 Conflicts on make-guile [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make-guile:armhf -1 as a solution to make:amd64 1
  Added make-guile:armhf to the remove list
  Fixing make:amd64 via keep of make-guile:armhf
Investigating (3) build-essential [ armhf ] < none -> 11.7 > ( devel )
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Considering make-guile:armhf 1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
Investigating (3) gcc-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel )
Broken gcc-4.9:armhf Depends on binutils [ armhf ] < none -> 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel ) (>= 2.25)
  Considering binutils:armhf 2 as a solution to gcc-4.9:armhf 3
  Holding Back gcc-4.9:armhf rather than change binutils:armhf
Investigating (3) gcc [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel )
Broken gcc:armhf Depends on gcc-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel ) (>= 4.9.2-1~)
  Considering gcc-4.9:armhf 3 as a solution to gcc:armhf 1
  Holding Back gcc:armhf rather than change gcc-4.9:armhf
Investigating (3) g++ [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel )
Broken g++:armhf Depends on gcc [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel ) (>= 4:4.9.2-2)
  Considering gcc:armhf 1 as a solution to g++:armhf 0
  Holding Back g++:armhf rather than change gcc:armhf
Investigating (3) g++-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel )
Broken g++-4.9:armhf Depends on gcc-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel ) (= 4.9.2-10)
  Considering gcc-4.9:armhf 3 as a solution to g++-4.9:armhf 0
  Holding Back g++-4.9:armhf rather than change gcc-4.9:armhf
Investigating (4) build-essential [ armhf ] < none -> 11.7 > ( devel )
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on gcc [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel ) (>= 4:4.9.1)
  Considering gcc:armhf 1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Re-Instated binutils:armhf
  Re-Instated gcc-4.9:armhf
  Re-Instated gcc:armhf
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on g++ [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel ) (>= 4:4.9.1)
  Considering g++:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Re-Instated g++-4.9:armhf
  Re-Instated g++:armhf
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Considering make-guile:armhf 1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
Investigating (4) binutils [ armhf ] < none -> 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
Broken binutils:armhf Conflicts on binutils [ amd64 ] < 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel )
  Considering binutils:amd64 2 as a solution to binutils:armhf 2
  Holding Back binutils:armhf rather than change binutils:amd64
Investigating (5) build-essential [ armhf ] < none -> 11.7 > ( devel )
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Considering make-guile:armhf 1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
Investigating (5) gcc-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel )
Broken gcc-4.9:armhf Depends on binutils [ armhf ] < none -> 2.25-5+deb8u1 > ( devel ) (>= 2.25)
  Considering binutils:armhf 2 as a solution to gcc-4.9:armhf 3
  Holding Back gcc-4.9:armhf rather than change binutils:armhf
Investigating (5) gcc [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel )
Broken gcc:armhf Depends on gcc-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel ) (>= 4.9.2-1~)
  Considering gcc-4.9:armhf 3 as a solution to gcc:armhf 1
  Holding Back gcc:armhf rather than change gcc-4.9:armhf
Investigating (5) g++ [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel )
Broken g++:armhf Depends on gcc [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel ) (>= 4:4.9.2-2)
  Considering gcc:armhf 1 as a solution to g++:armhf 0
  Holding Back g++:armhf rather than change gcc:armhf
Investigating (5) g++-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel )
Broken g++-4.9:armhf Depends on gcc-4.9 [ armhf ] < none -> 4.9.2-10 > ( devel ) (= 4.9.2-10)
  Considering gcc-4.9:armhf 3 as a solution to g++-4.9:armhf 0
  Holding Back g++-4.9:armhf rather than change gcc-4.9:armhf
Investigating (6) build-essential [ armhf ] < none -> 11.7 > ( devel )
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on gcc [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel ) (>= 4:4.9.1)
  Considering gcc:armhf 1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on g++ [ armhf ] < none -> 4:4.9.2-2 > ( devel ) (>= 4:4.9.1)
  Considering g++:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
Broken build-essential:armhf Depends on make [ armhf ] < none -> 4.0-8.1 > ( devel )
  Considering make:armhf 0 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
  Considering make-guile:armhf 1 as a solution to build-essential:armhf 9999
Done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line causing problems:

```
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential:armhf
```

You don’t need `build-essential:armhf` to cross-compile. You should remove that; `docker build` should then be able to build a container without issue.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like there's some dependencies that can't be installed. What exactly is hard to say.

Unfortunately, `apt`'s output is not very helpful when it encounters a problem it cannot fix. You can coax it into giving more output, though—by specifying `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes` on the apt command line. that should give you more detail on what it's trying to do, and hopefully allow you to fix it.

If that doesn't fix it for you, please run apt with that option and post the output.

Comment: Thanks, i added the debug output to my post. Sadly I have no clue what it means.